# Calculate (not design!) the minimum of a stack in Java

Tags: java, stack, time-complexity

I want to write a function to **calculate** (not design) the minimum of a given stack. I thought that I can find that easily in the net but I found *nothing* about that. All what I found is to how to design a stack with a getMinimum function.

The difference is that when you design such a stack, you will gradually construct your stack (push and pop) and updating the minimum value after any operation. I was thinking, how if you have a given stack and you want to calculate the minimum of this stack, how can you deal with that? Perhaps, I don't reason very well or I'm asking myself the wrong answers or I don't understand very well the concept of the stack but it surprise me to don't find any answer about that in the net, even after a lot of search...

Here is my attempt :

```
    public static int min(Stack stack){
        Stack temp = new Stack();
        int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
                int value = stack.pop();
                temp.push(value);
                result =  (result >= value)? value : result;
            }
    //stack is empty now, I have to recuperate it from the temp stack
             while(!temp.isEmpty()) {
                     stack.push(temp.pop());
             }

             return result;
      }
```

In this code, I use my own implementation for Stack and Node. But as you can see, the code is very simple. I wrote this post mainly because I'm asking myself a lot of questions about that.

Especially, I want to ask you please three main questions :

- What is the time and the space complexity for this function? I think it's O(N), is it right? I always get some difficulties to calculate that in my program. It's normally O(2*N) (which equals O(N) ) since we run through the stack node per node.
- Is my approach logical or not? From what I understand, if you want to get acces to the kth element in a stack, you have to pop the k-1 previous element. Or here, in my opinion, it's absolutely not logical to pop an entire stack if we just want to calulate its minimum (if you want to manipulate again the same stack). It's why I did a second while loop to keep the stack in its original state.
- Perhaps, we can made a copy of the stack, but I read that cloning objects in Java is no that easy and I'm wondering if it will not be very consuming for a little function like this?

Thanks

Comment: Also, if you don't want to modify the "addToStack" function you can't really make this min function any better, so yes your solution is what I'd attempt too. I'd also say that the complexity is O(n)

Comment: Euh, I tried that in my IDE and it works. But honestly, it's not really about calculating the min (it can be the max or anything else). It's more about understanding the concept and the utility behind the concept of a stack :)

Comment: Yes, yes and yes (don't use clone, ever, I doubt your attack class implements it reasonably). Also this would really be better at code review, but the general idea is sound.

Comment: @salamanka44 I could take a better look at it if you could provide a complete code sample. Like the whole file + Stack. https://gist.github.com

Comment: If you can get the stack and are using java 8 you can just simply do.. `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(nums).min().getAsInt());`

Comment: @Dodekeract  as you asked for, you can find my code here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ae4ab35a8443ffd8272de073fc04dc19

Comment: I'd prefer `result = Math.min(result, value);` also you could eliminate the temporary `int value` if your `Stack` implements `peek()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Time and space are indeed O (n) as you explained.
2. There is logic in your method. However, You can implement your Stack in such a manner that would allow you to implement peek (int index) - (for example if your stack is based on array.) and then you wont have to pop in re insert all the elements.
3. You can save additional sorted data structure inside your Stack implementation that will allow you to fetch the minimal value in O (1) but will double the space used. in the end, its always a trade off between space and time.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a better option will be to utilize `Vector` abilities as a `Stack` is a subclass of `Vector` in Java

```
public static int min(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    Integer[] elements = stack.toArray(new Integer[1]);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        if(elements[i] < min) {
            min=elements[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

This shall give you a better performance for large input data over your own implemented method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One correction.  I don't think the `[ ]` operator is overloaded. Instead of `elements[i]` say, `elements.get(i)`

Comment: Its an Array and arrays are accessed using `[ ]` only. please see very first line.

Comment: By why make a copy of the array with `stack.toArray` ?  Just enumerate from `0..stack.size()-1`.  I'll post an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack class in Java inherits from Vector.  So you can just enumerate over the items without having to do any push, pop, or copy operations.  With that being said, here's an O(N) solution:

```
public static int min(Stack stack) {
    int m = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {

        int current = stack.get(i).intValue();

        if (current < m)
        {
             m = current;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier using recursion:

```
int min(Stack stack) {
    if(stack.isEmpty())
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int temp = stack.pop();
    int min = Math.min(temp, min(stack));
    stack.push(temp);

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution break when using a huge stack? Shouldn't this easily cause a "too much recursion" error?

Comment: @Dodekeract Sure, there is no free lunch in CS.